# Deploy MSTest projects

Tags: c#, mstest

I was wondering if it would be possible to either write or deploy an existing test runner along side my MVC application. The tests could be referenced from the test Runner application and deployed separately from the main application.

The aim is to run the tests remotely on client site as a sort of diagnostics tool.

It would be great if we could have a little more information when things go wrong.

Is this possible?

Comment: MSTest is considered to be part of VS. I think you can deploy it to CI machines, but probably cannot on a customer machine of yours. Read Microsoft EULA and consult your lawyers.

Comment: I was thinking the same... perhaps I might need to consider something like NUnit

Comment: or wait, as Microsoft does plan to open source MSTest if you read from their GitHub discussions.

Comment: @LexLi do you have a link? Which Github discussions are you referring to?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/374